# Rearrange of a nested List with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, nested

I'm currently working on a project where I've read line data from a spreadsheet. The structure of the base data can be seen in the attached image on the left side. It can also be seen that I would like to rearrange the data in two steps.

[Image1: Steps to sort the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlISS.png)

- Firstly, I combine the element with the same `PartName` and combine the two coordinate pairs on one line. I store the coords in a nested list.
- Secondly, I would like to combine the elements with the same `ID` and combine the coords again. Important is that the List keeps its order and that no duplicates are existing in the end. Something like this:`{x1y1,x2y2}{x2y2,x3y3}=>{x1y1,x2y2,x3y3}`.

The number of element parts is generic and therefore also the number of coordinate pairs.

Here are my simplified object classes I'm currently using:

```
public class ElmLine
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string PartName {get; set;}
    public List<CoordList> CoordList { get; set; }
}

public class CoordList
{
    public decimal XCord { get; set; }
    public decimal YCord { get; set; }
}
```

This is my approach for step 1. I rearranged the base list and stored the coordination pairs in a nested list named `CoordList`.

```
public void BuildLinesFormSegments(IList<ElmLine> filteredLine)
    {
        // Merge line parts and add FROM and TO to each line part 
        var combinedLineParts = filteredLine
            .GroupBy(c => new { c.Fid, c.FidPart }).Select(g => new ElmLine()
            {
                Id = g.Select(c => c.Id).First(),
                PartName = g.Select(c => c.PartName).First(),
                CoordList = g.Select(c => new CoordList() 
                            { XCord = c.CoordX, YCord = c.CoordY }).ToList(),
            }).ToList();
    }
```

The resulting list `combinedLineParts` looks like this:

```
var list = new LineParts<ElmLine>
{
    new ElmLine {Name = 1, CoordList = new List<CoordList>
        {new CoordList {XCord = x1, YCord = y1}, new CoordList { XCord = x2, YCord = y2 }} },
    new ElmLine {Name = 1, CoordList = new List<CoordList>
        {new CoordList {XCord = x2, YCord = y2}, new CoordList { XCord = x3, YCord = y3 }} },
    new ElmLine {Name = 2, CoordList = new List<CoordList>
        {new CoordList {XCord = x11, YCord = y11}, new CoordList { XCord = x12, YCord = y12 }} },
    new ElmLine {Name = 2, CoordList = new List<CoordList>
        {new CoordList {XCord = x12, YCord = y12}, new CoordList { XCord = x13, YCord = y13 }} },
};
```

Unfortunately I'm stuck at this point and I have no good idea to proceed with step2. It would be great if someone could give me a hint what I could do next.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So now you want to create step 3, which is grouping by Name, then taking all `CoordList`s and creating a new `CoordList` which contains `x1, x2, x3` for Name = 1? Where does the other `x2` go and why?

Comment: Based on the image, you just want step 3 to group by ID, eliminating duplicate coordinates, and dropping Name entirely, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot of thinking and the hints of [StriplingWarrior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120955/striplingwarrior) I was able to solve my problem. To complete this post, I would like to show how I made it.

The `### Parts ###`in the comment line are references to the `image1` in the initial post. I solved my problem in these three steps and it can be seen what I make with my data in each step.

To give a better understanding of what I'm doing you can imagine domino stones. Each stone chain consists of a generic number of stones which are in the base data not in a line.

Base Data: `{1,4} {1,3} {2,9} {2,7} {3,6} {3,3} {4,4} {4,7}` (a List with `{StoneNr,SideValue}` each line is Half a Stone)

Result of Part 1: `[4|3] [9|7] [6|3] [4|7]` (a list with the stones combined)

Result of Part 2: `[9|7] [7|4] [4|3] [3|6]` (a rearranged list where all pairs are next to each other like a domino chain)

Result of Part 3: `{9,7,4,3,6}` (a string with the numbers in the necessary order)

In fact the stone values are coordinates and therefore pairs of numbers and the stone chains are lines in a 2D-plane but the principle keeps the same.

```
        // ### Part 1 ###
        var combinedLineParts = filteredLine.GroupBy(c => new { c.Fid, c.FidPart})
                .Select(g => new ElmLine()
        {
            Fid = g.Select(c => c.Fid).First(),
            FidPart = g.Select(c => c.FidPart).First(),
            CoordList = g.Select(c => new CoordList() 
                                          {XCord = c.CoordX, YCord = c.CoordY}).ToList()
                         .GroupBy(x => new {x.XCord, x.YCord})
                         .Select(x => x.First()).ToList(),
        }).ToList();

        // ### Part 2 ###
        foreach (var group in combinedLineParts.GroupBy(c => c.Fid))
        {
            List<List<CoordList>> coordList = group.Select(c => c.CoordList).ToList();

            if (coordList.Count > 2)
            {
                int[] startPoint = FindStartPoint(coordList);

                // if start point is not on top of the list, 
                // move it to the top (to: {0,0})
                if (startPoint[0] > 0 || startPoint[1] > 0)
                {
                    SwapElements(coordList, startPoint, new int[] { 0, 0 });
                }

                // Rearange List to sort the lineparts
                int groupNumb = 0;
                while (groupNumb < coordList.Count - 1)
                {
                    RearrangeList(coordList, groupNumb);
                    groupNumb++;
                }
            }
        // ### Part 3 ###
            // create a new list with the sorted lineparts
            combinedLines.Add( new ElmLine()
                {
                    Fid = group.Key,
                    CoordList = coordList.SelectMany(d => d)
                                         .Select(c => new {c.XCord, c.YCord})
                                         .Distinct()
                                         .Select(c => new CoordList() 
                                            {XCord = c.XCord, YCord = c.YCord}).ToList(), 
                });
        }
        return combinedLines;
```

`FindStartPoint(), SwapElements(), RearrangeList()` are my own methodes I made to solve my specific sorting problem.

Answer (score 2):

Step 3 really doesn't need to rely on Step 2. You're just grouping by ID and keeping the distinct coordinate values:

```
var result = filteredLine
        .GroupBy(c => c.Fid)
        .Select(g => new ElmLine()
        {
            Id = g.Key,
            CoordList = g
                .Select(c => { c.CoordX, c.CoordY })
                .Distinct()
                .Select(c => new CoordList() 
                        { XCord = c.CoordX, YCord = c.CoordY })
                .ToList(),
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: That's almost what I was looking for. What can I do to make sure that before I delete the duplicates the duplicates are next to each other? In case the list looks like this: {x1y1,x2y2}{x3y3,x4y4}{x2y2,x3y3}=>{x1y1,x2y2}{x2y2,x3y3}{x3y3,x4y4}=>{x1y1,x2y2,x3y3,x4y4} Unfortunately it's not possible to sort by numbers.

Comment: @DominikAmrein: If the duplicates are deleted, why does it matter if they're "next to each other"? The code given will do what you've asked by maintaining the order of first occurrence. `{1,a,x1,y1},{1,a,x2,y2},{1,b,x3,y3},{1,b,x2,y2}` will yield `{1,[{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3}]}` because the first instance of `x2,y2` was encountered before `x3,y3`.

Comment: The reason for my question is that these coordinates draws a line. This means I've to be sure that the order is guaranteed. I can check this just as long the duplicates are not deleted.

Comment: The line looks in the end like this: `{x1,y1}---------{x2,y2}--------{x3,y3}` And I can't be sure that the provided data are always in the necessary order.

Comment: @DominikAmrein: That's tricky, because if you don't know that the data will be in the right order then how will you know that `{x1,y1}` are really the ones you want to have go first? What if the input was `{1,a,x2,y2},{1,a,x1,y1},{1,b,x3,y3},{1,b,x2,y2}`? You could figure out that `{x2,y2}` are duplicates and therefore represent a link in the chain, but how would you know whether `{x1,y1}` or `{x3,y3}` are supposed to represent the beginning of the line?

Comment: There is always a pair of xy-coords which defines a line segment. For instance: `{x1y1}-----{x2y2}` and so on. When I order all line segment that always the duplicates are next to each other, the start and end of the line is already at the right place in the list because these coords has no duplicate. As it can be seen here: `{x1y1,x2y2}{x2y2,x3y3}{x3‌​y3,x4y4}=>{x1y1,x2y2‌​,x3y3,x4y4}`

Comment: @DominikAmrein: Why not `{x4y4,x3y3}{x3y3,x2y2}{x2​y2,x1y1}=>{x4y4,x3y3​,x2y2,x1y1}`? That has all the same coordinates, just in a different order. If the original order could be wrong, when you see an `{x1y1}` and an `{x2y2}`, how do you know that it's `{x1​y1,x2y2}` and not `{x2​y2,x1y1}`?

Comment: I need just the ends of the line at the edges of the list. The orientation is not important just the order of the segments. When you check my attached image you can see that my initial idea was to group the segments by `PartName`. This way I've all the coord pairs of a segment combined (step1). In Step2 I need a way to sort the coord pairs by the duplicates to arrange the line.

Comment: @DominikAmrein: As I said in my earlier comment, this is not a "grouping" and "sorting" in the traditional sense. I would put all of the coordinates into some kind of an indexing structure, like an `ILookup`, indexed by an anonymous class with the `{x= ..., y = ...}` structure. Then, look through those until you find one that only has one item in it, and use that as a starting point. If you have trouble, create a new question that highlights the specific point you're struggling with.